# difference between the the means of subsampling from an unbiased sample

Tags: probability, combinatorics, convergence-divergence, sampling, monte-carlo

Suppose I have a distribution  with mean M. Also, assume we have a set of i.i.d samples of size n denoted by X=$\{x_1,x_2,...,x_n\}$ from . As a result, all $x_1,...,x_n$ are independent with identical distribution.

We know that [X]=M.

Now suppose I derive another set of subsamples without replacement of size m from X where m ≤ n. Let's call this new subsamples Y=$\{y_1,y_2,...,y_m\}$.

Now can I say [Y]=M?

Based on the rule of total expectation, we know that [Y]=[[Y|X]]. I am guessing that using this law we may be able to answer yes to the previous question as the set X is not fixed.

If my claim is not correct, please give a counterexample or prove why we cannot show $ \mathbb{E}[X]\neq \mathbb{E}[Y]$

Comment: Please see [this tutorial and reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset math on this site.

Comment: Thanks, is it possible for you to answer my question?